# padding on the left twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to understand which part of twitter bootstrap css code is responsible for the left padding whitespace in this example: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html
but does not appear in this example: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The first example is in a div with the class hero-unit.  The hero-unit class has its padding set to 60px.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, in this particular case, described above, it depends on your screen resolution. As Twitter Bootstrap uses responsive CSS, the width of the `starter-template.html` changes discretely, and in some cases padding is minimal. You could try changing your browser window width to see how padding (container width) changes dynamically. The same for `hero.html`, but as `hero.html` contains more content, the width in `hero.html` example switches earlier than in `starter-template.html` at the same screen resolution.